# get the file name from the path

Tags: shell, unix, awk, cut

I have a file `file.txt` having the following structure:-

```
./a/b/c/sdsd.c
./sdf/sdf/wer/saf/poi.c
./asd/wer/asdf/kljl.c
./wer/asdfo/wer/asf/asdf/hj.c
```

How can I get only the c file names from the path.
i.e., my output will be

```
sdsd.c
poi.c
kljl.c
hj.c
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this simpy with using awk.

set field seperator FS="/" and $NF will print the last field of every record.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"} {print $NF}' file.txt
```

or

```
awk -F/ '{print $NF}' file.txt
```

Or, you can do with cut and unix command rev like this

`rev file.txt | cut -d '/' -f1 | rev`

Comment: Don't forget `awk '{print $NF}' FS=/` and `awk '{$0=$NF}1' FS=/`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `basename` command:

```
basename /a/b/c/sdsd.c
```

will give you sdsd.c

For a list of files in `file.txt`, this will do:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do basename "$line"; done < file.txt
```

Comment: The above while loop will fail cryptically for several different inputs. Try it with file names containing backslashes, file names that start/end with spaces, file names that contain spaces, file names that contain globbing characters, etc., etc... Always write your loops as `while IFS= read -r line` and always quote your variables unless you have a specific reason not to and understand the consequences.

Comment: @EdMorton Good point. I usually quote the variables, but forget about the IFS= part. Thanks for pointing it out. Updated the answer.

Comment: Don't forget the "-r" option for read or your script will still fail for file names that contain backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple one (`$NF` is the last column of current line):

```
awk -F/ '{print $NF}' file.txt
```

or using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) & [*parameter expansion*](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe):

```
while read file; do echo "${file##*/}"; done < file.txt
```

or `bash` with `basename` :

```
while read file; do basename "$file"; done < file.txt
```

**OUTPUT**

```
sdsd.c
poi.c
kljl.c
hj.c
```

Comment: Added _parameter expansion_ doc link

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
perl -F/ -ane 'print $F[@F-1]' your_file
```

Also you can use sed:

```
sed 's/.*[/]//g' your_file
```

Comment: awk is tagged by OP. But how come perl is part of bash?

Comment: +1 Perl is a shell tool when used in _one liner_ mode, and OP added _unix_ tag.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed 's|.*/||g' file
sdsd.c
poi.c
kljl.c
hj.c
```